# Getting strange result while using increment operator(++) in printf fuction

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I am executing this c program on gcc compiler and getting strange results.
So how is it possible

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  i =10;
  printf(" %d %d %d  ",i++,i++,i);  //output : 11 10 12
  return 0;
}
```

as per me result should be 10 11 12 but I am getting 11 10 12.
How is it possible?

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the order of evaluation of function arguments is [undefined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) so if you use the increment operator multiple times in the argument to a particular function there is no 'correct' answer, they may be evaluated in any arbitrary order.

Comment: i got what you said but if arguments are evaluated randomly then each time i execute program i should get different output as per order of evaluation of arguments but i get same result each time i execute program ,why?

Comment: @ineevparmar: undefined != ramdomly.

Answer (score 1):

Please familiarize yourself with the concept of **Sequence points**. Only at such defined sequence points is guaranteed that all side effects of previous evaluations are performed. There are no sequence points between the list of arguments of a function. So, it leads to *undefined behavior*.